# Parameters URL request, undefined

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I want to have a button that redirect me to an url like this: **task-details/1**

For this, in HTML I did something like this:

```
  <ul *ngFor="let task of tasks" class="list-group list-group-flush">
     <li class="list-group-item">
         {{task.description}} <button class="btn-success" [routerLink]="['/task-details', task.id]"></button>
     </li>
  </ul>
```

router:

```
{path: 'task-details/:id', component: TaskDetailComponent}
```

When I clicked the button, I received: **task-details/undefined**. For {{task.description}} it appears the correct values. How can I rewrite the routerLink  for receive: task-details/1 ?

Comment: How is the tasks object?

Comment: @axl-code tasks: Task[]; and I defined Task as a class with id, description and date.

Comment: export class Task {
  id: number;
  description: string;
  date: string;
}

Comment: Can you confirm that task.id has really any value?  Try printing the values for debugging - perhaps change `{{task.description}}` to `{{task.description}} - {{task.id}}` and see what shows in browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <ul *ngFor="let task of tasks" class="list-group list-group-flush">
     <li class="list-group-item">
         {{task.description}} <button class="btn-success" routerLink="/task-details/"+task.taskId></button>
     </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: have you checked that your "tasks" list is not empy? can you paste your .ts code?

Comment: I checked the tasks list: for an object from the tasks list I received:
Task : {taskId: ' ', description: 'do some exercise', data: '12 February'}. In Angular I had id defined as "id" and in backend I had the id defined as "taskId", now I changed the  id ---> taskId, and it's working now... I don't know why.. but it's working...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207673/discussion-between-abc-and-doflamingo19).

Answer (score 0):

u can try like this if task.id is not null [routerLink]="['/task-details/'+ task.id]"